# MVC parent/child sites in IIS using OWIN is not passing identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I have a requirement to nest one site under another in IIS so users can go back and forth between the two without logging into both. I have done this previously with MVC sites with success by removing most of the child's web.config so it inherits the parent web.config and setting a machinekey manually in the parent config.

In the parent I set the machine key manually and verified that the child is picking it up.

I have tested two MVC 5 web apps with individual user accounts (Identity). I setup the second app as a virtual application under the main app, using the same app pool. The stock MVC apps work fine. I log into the parent, navigate to the child and it picks up the identity. I can verify because it says 'welcome bdamore@xxxxxx.com' in both parent and child sites.

But the stock ones are using the stock login/ApplicationUserManager/ApplicationSignInManager methodology, whereas our parent app has a lot of customized OWIN.

Where a stock MVC site's login method uses: *"SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(...)"*

our parent site is using:
*"HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(...)"*

Parent site still uses: *"@User.Identity.GetUserName()"* in the _loginPartial.cshtml just like the mostly stock MVC5 child site but the child **NEVER** picks up the Identity.User or any User Claims from the parent like the stock MVC5 parent/child sites do.

Here is some of the login:

```
var hash = _cryptographyService.HashPassword(model.Password);
        var token = _profileService.Login(model.Email, hash);
        if (token != null)
        {
            var userData = SerializeCustomUser(token);
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            identity.AddClaims(new List<Claim>
            {
              new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,model.Email),
              new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,model.Email),
              new Claim("UserId", token.UserId.ToString()),
              new Claim("RoleId", token.Role.ToString()),
              new Claim("SchoolId", token.SchoolId.ToString()),
              new Claim("CampusId", token.CampusId.ToString())
            });

            if (model.RememberMe)
            {
                Response.Cookies["UserName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Cookies["UserName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

            }
            Response.Cookies["UserName"].Value = model.Email.Trim();

            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(identity);
....
```

_ProfileService.Login goes to the Db and verifies the creds

here is the Startup.Auth.cs:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            CookieName="VerityAuthSession",
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider {
              OnValidateIdentity = context =>
              {
                var url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current?.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
                if (url?.IndexOf("signalr") != -1 || url?.IndexOf("TwilioInfo/GetInboundCallDetails".ToLower()) != -1 || url?.IndexOf("CreateLogOffEvent".ToLower()) !=-1)
                {
                  if(url?.IndexOf("signalr") != -1)
                  {
                    var cookie = new System.Web.HttpCookie("tmpsession", context?.Identity?.Claims?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "UserId")?.Value);
                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current?.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                  }
                  context.RejectIdentity();
                  return Task.FromResult<int>(0);
                }
                DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

                context.OwinContext.Request.Set<double>("time.Remaining",
                       context.Properties.ExpiresUtc.Value.Subtract(now).TotalSeconds);
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current?.Response.Cookies.Add(new System.Web.HttpCookie("lastaccess", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy.HH.mm.ss")));
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
              },
              OnException = context => {},
              OnResponseSignIn = context =>
              {
                context.Properties.AllowRefresh = true;
                context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(double.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[EnvironmentConsts.SessiontTimeout] ?? "45"));
              }
            }
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
        // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
        // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

        var signalRConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[EnvironmentConsts.SignaRDbConnectionName].ConnectionString;
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(signalRConnectionString); //for using SignalR with loadbalancer we need this configuration
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
```

*There is some code in the startup to handle when our site ajax's to twillio so it doesn't extend their session as if they are navigating.*

Comment: Can both sites read the authorization cookie?

Comment: how can I find out? I see it in Chrome/Fiddler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

1. I needed to copy over the entire customized `app.UseCookieAuthentication(...`
   portion into the StartupAuth.cs file. The parent is giving the cookie a 'Name' property and apparently, it needs the same name in both apps.
2. the following needs to be in the OnApplicationStarted() method of our custom setup: `AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;`

Our architect set this up for Ninject by having our global.asax.cs inherit form a file called 'ParentApplication.cs" in the App_Startup folder. There, the ParentApplication.cs file inherits from NinjectHttpApplication.

In this file there is a method:

```
protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
```

Hope this helps someone else.